# Dijkstra's example of an ambiguous program

Tags: dijkstra, ambiguity

Salutations.  Dijkstra wrote that even a few lines of seemingly simple code could be hopelessly ambiguous.  In at least one work, which I can't find now to save my life, he gave a little example program to demonstrate this ambiguity.  Can anybody point me to a paper of his where he includes one of these examples?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to programmers.SE

Comment: [Reposted on Programmers and has answers there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/81379/dijkstras-example-of-an-ambiguous-program)